# How to apply two shopping cart rule on cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have two shopping cart price rule. One has 5% discount on product with sku `product1` and second has 7% discount on product with sku `product2`.

These rule working seperatly. But when cart has both products then calulation is different as I want.

For example :

product1's price is 500 and product2's price is 700.
when product1 is in cart 1st rule will apply and `(500*5)/100 = 25` is my discount on cart.

similarly when product2 is in cart then discount is `49`.

But when both product is in cart then discount is `(500 - (500*5)/100)*7/100 = 33.25` showing but I want to add discount `25+49=74`.

How to do this, Is there any setting for this?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://prntscr.com/c549l8) is what you are looking for, you can do this by moving the product conditions from the `Conditions` tab to the `Actions` tab in the section (`Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions`)

If you set the conditions at the `Conditions` tab, when the conditions are true the discount is applied to the Cart Subtotal. But if you set the conditions in the `Actions` tab, the discount is applied to only those items in which that condition is true.

Hope this helps.